# PFQuery not updating objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following method which is called in `viewDidLoad`. And it works fine. But, in another method, when I change a value and try to call the following method again, it doesn't update. Why does it do this and how can I fix this?

```
- (void)initialStuff {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            PFFile *file = currentFriend.photo;
            [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    self.chosenImage.image = image;
                }
            }];
            NSLog(@"worked");
            self.chosenText.text = currentFriend.text;

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentFriend.artwork]];
            self.songImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            self.songName.text = currentFriend.trackName;
            self.artistLabel.text = currentFriend.artist;

            self.songURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentFriend.preview];
        }
    }];
}
```

How come the query is finding outdated info?

Comment: It should not be behaving like what you describe. Or maybe your changes are not saved yet?

Comment: When I quit the app and rebuild, it loads the saved information. Is it possible that since it is setting the objects in background that when the method is called, it is still running in the background?

Comment: No, the background does not meaning put the operation to the background. It means that it's operating an asynchronous call. So, you should check your code rather than finding Parse' error. Or, maybe the data is latest but you have not refresh your UI?

Comment: In the code above, you can see that it is refreshing the UI.

Comment: By the time you fetch it, how can you make sure your data is saved already? What if it's not saved?

Comment: I don't know. I use [currentFriend saveInBackground] in the other class.

Comment: Before completing of first request and updating you are calling update again with different values..So, I think its not updating. Try calling the method after delay using performSelector..!

Comment: What do I put for withObject in [self performSelector...]?

Comment: You might be have a timing mismatch problem. Make sure the data is saved when you perform fetch.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that